# Angular material: displaying icons to the right of mat-chip

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-5

I have a mat-chip and have content in it. Also I have a cancel icon in it.
I set the mat-chip a fixed width, so I want the cancel icon to always float to the right.But the cancel icon is not floating to the right. I tried multiple css techniques but nothing worked.

```
<mat-chip *ngIf= "item?.name">
   {{ item.name}}
   <mat-icon matChipRemove (click)="removeAssignments(dataItem)">cancel</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well `mat-chip` has `display: inline-flex` as a property, so you need to manipulate the child elements using flex related properties. For your case:

```
mat-chip {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

will do the trick. [consider this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) into flexbox if you want to fully experience angular material, as there are a lot of things that are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the icon before the item (`{{ item.name}}`):

```
<mat-chip *ngIf= "item?.name">
   <mat-icon matChipRemove (click)="removeAssignments(dataItem)">cancel</mat-icon>
   {{ item.name}}
</mat-chip>
```